# What is AspectJ context binding?

Tags: aspectj

can anyone explains to me what "context binding" at runtime in AspectJ is, and in what ways is it different from reflection? 
In particular, if I need to get an annotation from a class woven by a given aspect, context binding:

`after(MyAnnotation annotation) : execution(* Foo.*(..)) && @this(annotation)`

or reflection:

`MyAnnotation myAnnotation = thisJoinPoint.getThis().getClass().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);`

can be used, but what is the best solution (that is, the quickest one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using the former.  Creating `thisJoinPoint` objects are expensive since all fields must be filled in when accessed.  Therefore, AspectJ will only create one if required.

Accessing the annotation via advice is generally faster since the compiler has more of a chance to optimize.  Furthermore, it is more strongly types (your second example has a type error).

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the error. But could you please give me some more insight of what context binding is and how it works? I couldn't find any useful info on it.

Comment: Context binding is just a fancy term for the binding that happens inside of pointcuts.  This happens inside of `@this`, `this` `target`, `args`, etc.  It is different from regular reflection since the compiler knows exactly what to bind at compile time.  With reflection, however, the compiler has a much more difficult time optimizing since reflection happens at runtime.  If you want any more details on the implementation, then I'd recommend asking on the aspectj-users mailing list: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/userlists.php